# Adwhirl test ad issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, adwhirl

In my application i have integrated ad-whirl, in the ad-whirl setup i have configured 3 ad networks like iad, ad-mob and Millennial Media but ads are coming only from ad-mob network. Even i have turned off both iad and ad-mob network in  ad network setting in ad-whirl.

I have integrated all the 3 ad network sdks

[image]

And i have returned this code in adwhirlViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    adView=[AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];

    [self.view addSubview:adView];  
}

- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView {
    NSLog(@"Ad received");
    CGSize adSize = [adView actualAdSize];
    NSLog(@"Net work Name %@",[adWhirlView mostRecentNetworkName]);
    CGRect newFrame = adView.frame;
    newFrame.size = adSize;

    newFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/ 2;

    newFrame.origin.y=385;
    NSLog(@"frame size %f,%f",newFrame.origin.x,newFrame.origin.y);
    adView.frame = newFrame;

}

- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey {
        // return your SDK key  
    return kSampleAppKey;

}

-(void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
    NSLog(@"Ad not Received");
    NSLog(@"Net work Name %@",[adWhirlView mostRecentNetworkName]);
    CGRect tempFrame = adView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.y = -adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = tempFrame;

}
```

But ads are coming only from admob. please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What SDK key does kSampleAppKey map to? Are you sure that it maps to the key given to you by the AdWhirl console when you set up your ad placement?

Comment: Yes that key only. i have registered and integrated adwhirl SDK with that 32 digit serial key only.

Comment: So you're sure you're using the 32 digit key that the AdWhirl console gave you (when you set up your placement online)?

Comment: s i am sure. that key only i am using.[of-course i got that 32 bit key value after the online payment from adwhirl console]. matter is i am getting test ads only. but that ads coming properly with out fail.